# Retrofit. Как полученные данные записать в переменные для их дальнейшего использования?

Tags: java, android

Не могу разобраться, как сделать это.

```
 Call<RequestBody> call = mService.postToken(post);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<RequestBody> call, @NonNull Response<RequestBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
              // вот здесь что-то нужно прописать, но я не знаю
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<RequestBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Это pojo

```
public class RequestBody implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("id_token")
@Expose
private String idToken;

public RequestBody(String idToken) {
    super();
    this.idToken = idToken;
}

public String getIdToken() {
    return idToken;
}

public void setIdToken(String idToken) {
    this.idToken = idToken;
}
```

}

А это интерфейс:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(" ")
    Call<List<RequestBody>> postParams(@Field("id_token") String id_token);
```

Как этот id_token записать в переменную String?

Comment: можно префы использовать или класс для этого сделать

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что вам не понятно. Вроде все правильно.
В успешной ветке создается свой класс

```
RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody(response.body())
String IdToken = requestBody.idToken
```

И используйте его как вам удобно.

Если же вопрос был, как использовать во всем проекте, то наверно лучшим решением будет сохранить в SharedPreference, и в нужном месте вытаскивать и использовать.
Что касательно класса, мне не понятно, зачем вы отправляете token_id, а потом получаете его (возможно другое, вдруг у вас логика такая)